# apt-get vs git clone

Tags: ros, navigation, ros2, git, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone

Im new to ROS platform and im about to build my first real world robot using ROS. M question might sound bad or something but i have to ask since im only a beginner.

which is the best practice for installing ROS packages, apt-get or git clone. For example if i want to install the gmapping package for my robot, should i:

- Install the gmapping package using
  sudo apt-get command and as far as i
  know if i use this command, the
  gmapping package will be available
  for all workspaces and packages.
- Install the gmapping  package using
  git clone command.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/378379/apt-get-vs-git-clone/) by [Celebrimbor](https://answers.ros.org/users/74585/celebrimbor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2021-05-15

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-05-17**:
@miura: why did you add the `ros2` tag?

**Comment by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on 2021-05-17**:
@gvdhoorn , from your answer and comment, I decided that the question applies to ROS2 as well.

**Comment by [Celebrimbor](https://answers.ros.org/users/74585/celebrimbor/) on 2021-05-19**:
Thank you very much, sir, the answer was veryy helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's just my opinion of course -- and there will certainly be others with different opinions -- but see #q320046 for an earlier Q&A on this topic.

Technically that Q&A is about *how* to install packages, but I took the time there to add some more context and guidelines as to *when* to choose which method of installation.

Summarising: always prefer `apt` (or `dnf` now with RPM distributions supported), *unless* there is no release of a package for a specific OS, platform, CPU architecture or with a specific patch included. And for that last case building from source is really only necessary / acceptable until the main release (ie: the one installable using `apt`) gets the patch.

And a final comment:

> Install the gmapping package using git clone command.

`git clone`-ing a repository is **not** the same as installing a package.

It's only one step in a (potentially involved and time consuming) process.

But see #q320046.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-05-16**:
And although you mark this as `ros1`, I don't believe I'd change my answer in the context of ROS 2 (except of course the ROS 1 wiki is not used for ROS 2 packages).